# Nginx: rewrite port in url from reverse proxie'd app

Tags: nginx, url, https, url-rewriting, reverse

So I have set up a reverse proxy to tunnel my application.

Unfortunately the application thinks it is served via http and not https and gives out URLs with port 80.

How can I handle this in the nginx reverse proxy? (by rewriting maybe)

When I go on the page:

```
https://my.server.com
```

index.php loads, everything is okay

after clicking something I have a URL like this:

```
https://my.server.com:80/page/stuff/?redirect_to
```

which throws an error within the browser because my reverse proxy doesn't serve SSL on port 80.

How can I migitate this?

My current nginx ssl vhost for the site:

```
   ... ssl stuff ...
   add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
   add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:22228;
       proxy_buffering off;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_read_timeout 43800;
       proxy_pass_request_headers on;
       proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_pass_header Content-Type;
       proxy_pass_header Content-Disposition;
       proxy_pass_header Content-Length;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
   }
```

(yes I know my request headers look like a christmas tree )

Also bonus points if you show where the documentation addressing this issue is and what the mechanism is called.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Do you need to rewrite these URLs in HTTP 3xx redirect headers or in response body?

Comment: Hi and thanks Ivan. 
I need to strip the port and rewrite the URLs in the response my nginx gives back to the browser.

Comment: Instead of rewriting on nginx the response, why don't you change the app to go http port 80 OR https port 443 so there is no conflict? I mean, https and port 80 don't get along well. it's weird for the app to respond https AND port 80 at the same time.

Comment: Hi @flaixman. Thanks for your input. I have tried but unfortunately I can't change how the app behaves. This question is about finding a solution via nginx rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

For rewriting response body you can use [`http_sub_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html):

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:22228;
    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter_types text/css application/javascript; # in addition to text/html
    sub_filter "//my.server.com:80/" "//my.server.com/";
}
```

Many people says ([1](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1109#comment:2), [2](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/7ktzgumkmp-subfilter-proxypass-requires-no-gzip-encoding)) that you need to disable compression when using `sub_filter` directive:

```
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
```

For me, it works fine without this line in config, but it can be a feature of OpenResty which I use instead of nginx.

If your app generates HTTP 30x redirects with explicit indication of domain:port, you can rewrite `Location` header value with the [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) directive:

```
    proxy_redirect //my.server.com:80/ //my.server.com/;
```